# Half thickness of lead using a Ba-133m source, references?

Tags: experimental-physics, radioactivity, gamma-rays

I carried out an **experiment** to calculate the **half thickness** (half value layer) of lead.
The experiment was done using what i believe to be a Ba-133m source on this **software**: https://radiation-lab.software.informer.com

I am unsure of what the true gamma source is because it wrote Ba-133 on the program, but Ba-131 on the .csv file it produced.

My value for the half thickness came out to be about 4 mm. However, I am unable to find any sources to prove me right or wrong and perhaps even help identify which source I was truly using.

The only source I found is this: https://www.doseinfo-radar.com/Exposure_Rate_Constants_and_Lead_Shielding_Values%204.pdf?fbclid=IwAR3YsLWure2-GIRcHpa9eapLFyykTCXjue7F64nHKd-qNBmluRFyFgrwmao

In page 4 of this pdf the hvl for lead using barium sources can be found, and they are nowhere near close to my value.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: To show respect for the hard work that experimental physicists do, please do not say that you “carried out an experiment” if what you actually did was run a simulation program. Simulation software can be very useful, but it isn’t the same as doing a real-world experiment.

Comment: Sorry about that. I used "carried out an experiment" due to the lack of better wording.